# Ms graph API, Querying Bookings APIs using isnt working

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Im facing some challenges while working with MS Graph APIs , especially with Booking One.
Error is like below

> `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses`
> resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
> {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token
> validation failure. Invalid
> audience.","innerError":{"date":"2023-09-22T06:36:11","request-id":"5d73f58d-9297-4ca8-bfe6-bafee1ebc54b","client-request-id":"5d73f58d-9297-4ca8-bfe6-bafee1ebc54b"}}}

code I have done so far is

```
    public function listAppoinment($userPrincipalName){
    $this->graph->setAccessToken($this->grant_type_password());
    $event = $this->graph->createRequest("GET", "/solutions/bookingBusinesses")
        ->execute();

}

private function grant_type_password(){
    $configuration = [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'scope' => "api://$this->clientId/Userlogin",
            'username' => 'myMailid',
            'password' =>'password'
        ],
        'http_errors' => false,
        'curl' => [
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => false
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]
    ];
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $this->tenentId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $response = $guzzle->post($url, $configuration);
    $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
        $error = $responseBody->error ?? $response->getStatusCode();
        trigger_error($responseBody->error_description ?? $error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    return $responseBody->access_token;
}
```

and the permission given
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to grant admin consent for application permissions `BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All` and `Bookings.Read.All`.

But according to the doc

[List bookingBusinesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) - doesn't support application permissions

[Get bookingBusiness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) - supports application permissions

After granting admin consent, try both endpoints

```
GET /solutions/bookingBusinesses
GET /solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}
```